# API for amazon EC2 describe-instance

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to get the ip-adress of instances behind an ELB, AWS give us the EC2 command line interface for that but i need to get that with an API (like a http request) in my application.

So can we call an API from an application to get the ip-adress of the describe-instance object ?

Comment: Please show your research.

Comment: I need that for a django application, so i found boto for aws, but from the documentation i think that you only can take the ELB ip-adress and not the ip-adress of the servers behind. The command line tools give us that command : ec2-describe-instances [instance_id ...] [[--filter "name=value"] ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at ec2 metadata, which needs to be called from inside an ec2 running instance.

It is the same URL for any ec2 instance / region and the response would give the information about itself.

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

You could perform curl call or http call and wrap the response back.

The following are the details you would get from meta-call

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
kernel-id
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
network/
placement/
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

More info - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html